# is using a third party to serve localhost subdomains a security risk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, subdomain

I've been following Ryan Bates Railscast on Subdomains http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 and using lvh.me to serve localhost subdomains as detailed in the railscast.

Today I issued 'lsof | grep IPv4' to see my running processes,  and I noticed the following entries:

```
...
Finder      121 nellboy    8u    IPv4 0x7cade64       0t0       TCP lvh.me:58803->lvh.me:26164 (ESTABLISHED)
...
Dropbox     131 nellboy   24u    IPv4 0x7cb866c       0t0       TCP lvh.me:26164->lvh.me:58803 (ESTABLISHED)
...
GoogleTal 26427 nellboy   27u    IPv4 0xbc3666c       0t0       TCP lvh.me:64279 (LISTEN)
GoogleTal 26427 nellboy   30u    IPv4 0x9152270       0t0       TCP lvh.me:64279->lvh.me:64280 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby      54081 nellboy    4u    IPv4 0xbc36a68       0t0       TCP lvh.me:sunwebadmins (LISTEN)
...
Google    57647 nellboy   24u    IPv4 0x7539a68       0t0       TCP lvh.me:64280->lvh.me:64279 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I'm wondering why lvh.me is listed with my dropbox,  my google account etc.etc.  Is this a security risk?,  should I be worried?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume at some point in that video, you add an entry like:

```
127.0.0.1 lvh.me
```

to your `/etc/hosts` file.

This just adds a new name for your local system.

Check your output again with `lsof -n | grep IPv4` or `netstat -anp`, and you will probably see that all those `lvh.me:26146` turn into `127.0.0.1:26146`.

If my assumption is correct, none of the connections you pasted actually leave your local machine. The two listening sockets cannot accept connections except ones initiated on your local machine.

Comment: no,  you don't add anything to your hosts file,  you access the localhost via lvh.me:3000 (or whatever port number you're using).  In any case,  you are correct,  those lvh.me entries resolved to IP addresses.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ha! I should have looked into `lvh.me` more closely :) very clever. Just like adding the line I showed you, but it comes for free. :) Neat.